# Laravel model binding for select dropdown

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want the select dropdown value to be selected in my edit form.

In my controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $vedit = DB::table('vehicles')->where('id', $id)->first();
    $cartype= DB::table('car_category')->pluck('cartype'); 
    return view('vehicles.edit', compact('vedit','cartype'));
}
```

In view

```
{{ Form::label('Vehicle Type', 'Vehicle Type') }}
<select name="vehicle_type" class="form-control">
  @foreach($cartype as $cartypes)   
  <option value="{{ $cartypes}}">{{ $cartypes}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I 've tried the code,`$categories = [''=>''] + Car::pluck('cartype')->all();
            return view('vehicles.edit', compact('vedit','categories'));` in my controller

Comment: But it's also not working,It adds an another empty option in view

Comment: try with `pluck('cartype', 'id')` !!

Comment: No it's not working yet creates new option as empty

Comment: Sorry i didn't get the question before that :p and where is the choosen one how did you get it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157793/discussion-between-maraboc-and-saranya).

Comment: _Sorry i didn't get the question_-I want in model binding select option not selected the correct option value

Answer (score 2):

You can add `selected` attribute if it's the choosen one like this :

```
{{ Form::label('Vehicle Type', 'Vehicle Type') }}
<select name="vehicle_type" class="form-control">
    @foreach($cartype as $cartypes) 
        <option value="{{ $cartypes}}" {{ $cartypes == $vedit->vehicle_type ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $cartypes}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: I add it as answer to help other people finding the solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

By calling `pluck()` an array of values is already returned for the car types.

So just use it like this natively with Laravel Collective:

```
{!! Form::label('Vehicle Type', 'Vehicle Type') !!}
{!! Form::select('vehicle_type', $cartype, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Note, I have also changed your double curly braces. The double curly braces escape the output - given the `Form` facade returns HTML code, you want this to be unescaped.

More info on generating drop down lists with Laravel Collective; https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#drop-down-lists

**Edit** show currently selected value and old value if form fails validation:

```
{!! Form::label('Vehicle Type', 'Vehicle Type') !!}
{!! Form::select('vehicle_type', $cartype, old('vehicle_type', $vedit->vehicle_type), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code,but the value not get selected in my edit form.What 'll be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you saying the drop down has no values?

Comment: The drop shows the values but i want the value for the particular row to be selected

Comment: See my edit for a way to do this, as well as provide an option for the old input to be used if the form fails validation.

Comment: In view blade 
     ` {!! Form::model($vedit, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['vehicles.update', $vedit->id]]) !!}<div class="row">
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-6">
{!! Form::label('Vehicle Type', 'Vehicle Type') !!}
{!! Form::select('vehicle_type', $cartype, old('vehicle_type', $vedit->vehicle_type), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

</div>
</div>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

What version of Laravel are you using ? Looks like you're using Laravel Collective Form facade.

In that case, this should work fine:

```
{!! Form::label('Vehicle Type', 'Vehicle Type') !!}
{!! Form::select('vehicle_type', $cartype, $vedit->vehicle_type ?: old('vehicle_type), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Assuming `$vedit->vehicle_type` is your previously stored vehicle type. So it will pre-select that when editing. In case of creating new, `old('vehicle_type')` should persist the previously selected value on failed validations.

Comment: Thanks,I'm using laravel 5

Comment: That's how it should be. It will show all the options but the one for that row will be automatically selected. That's what `$vedit->vehicle_type` does.

Comment: But I can't guess why it's not selected

Comment: Try deleting your browser cache and/or try from a different browser. Some browsers have aggressive caching

Comment: In my form '{!! Form::model($vedit, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['vehicles.update', $vedit->id]]) !!}`

Comment: Just to clear out any confusion, it will only select previous value when you're editing. Make sure you're sending the correct `$vehicle` object from your controller (you may want to paste controller code too)

Something like:
```$vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);
return view('index')->with('vehicle', $vehicle);```