# show select option as default

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I laravel I want to create a select box which wants has '`select option,Approved,Rejected`' But I always shows Approved as default option in form

```
echo Form::select('request_status',[''=>'Select option','4'=>'Approved','7'=>'Rejected'],null,['class'=>'request_status report_filter default']);
```

How to make select option as default in laravel 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument in the `Form::select` is the selected item :

```
Form::select('request_status',[''=>'Select option','4'=>'Approved','7'=>'Rejected'],null,['class'=>'request_status report_filter default']);
```

Should be 4 for `Approved`:

```
Form::select('request_status',[''=>'Select option','4'=>'Approved','7'=>'Rejected'],4,['class'=>'request_status report_filter default']);
```

Or if you want to [do it  manualy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47016406/4881811)